# ELK:filebeat with ANSI encoding

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

My Tomcat logs are ANSI encoded (on windows) with Chinese. When I used filebeat to load those logs I found the Chinese was garbled. How can I deal with it ? Does filebeat have a setting to allow loading Chinese from ANSI encoding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Filebeat what the file's encoding is. There is a prospector option called [encoding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_encoding) for this. You can use a tool like Notepad++ that will guess at the encoding or you can examine the file with a hex editor to look at the BOM. Once you know the encoding you can add it to the config file.

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- paths:
    - 'C:\logs\*.log'
  encoding: windows-1252
```

Reference: [Encoding Descriptions](https://www.w3.org/TR/encoding)

Comment: Thank You A.J.But when i used this setting  encoding: windows-1252.I also got data with garbled. Like this     Starting service... ¾ÅÔÂ 09, 2016 9:19:03 ÉÏÎç org.apache.catalina.loader......

Comment: I was only guessing at the encoding based on the information you provided about it being ANSI with Chinese. To find out for sure open the file in hex editor and look for the BOM or use a tool like Notepad++ that will try to guess the encoding. Or ask the author of the application writing the file.

Comment: Ok thanks again A.J.I will try to get the true encoding. I am out now. When I have question later I will ask you again. Thank you somuch

Comment: HI!A.J.I am bcak and I deal my problem.When I open my log files with Notepad++ I get the encoding is GB2312.So I use encoding:GB2312.Then I get the true data.Sincere thanks!